# Git auto pull from repository into staging server?

Tags: php, git, github, ssh

I've been searching all over the place for an answer to this question. I know there are questions like this already but I can't seem to find a straight answer.

**How do I auto pull from a github repository into my staging server?**

I have my local files that I am pushing into my repository but then I want those files to automatically be pulled into my staging server.

My ssh deploy key is setup correctly in my github account. Whenever I ssh into my staging server and do a manual `git pull` command...it works just fine. But now I want that to be automatic.

I created a webhook in my github account with a payload URL that points to a PHP file with this code but i dont think its working:

```
<?php `git pull git@github.com:user/repo.git`; ?>
```

I'm not sure if I setup the webhook correctly.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: the first one should be a clone, the rest should be a pull

Comment: will that make it start working automatically?

Comment: You could config something like crontab to update your staging server's repo from github every some minutes. If you want to go any further, a CI tool like Jenkins could help a lot. Jenkins provides a set of build trigger plugins to monitor your github repo. A Jenkins job can be triggered by time or events that happen in your github repo. You could define what to do in a job.

Answer (score 1):

If the deployment script is in a different directory, be sure to CD into the correct directory in the staging server.

```
<?php `cd /your/repo/location && git pull`; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

follow these steps

1) in your staging server create a file called githubupdate.php and add below content in that file

```
<?php `git pull`;?>
```

2) now go to github account and open your repo's settings 
3) Click on webhooks and addwebhook, in webhook you have to add  above url e.g http://www.yoursite.com/githubupdate.php
4) now try to push from local and check it work ?